# How DB Connections Numbers Are Calculated?

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-rds

I have database connection number increased this morning, which never happen before. as shown below :

[image]

and I don't know why. because there's no user accessing this database. just cronjob which runs since last month and no changes.

so I was wondering, how this database connection number is calculated?

does each `SELECT`, `UPDATE` and `INSERT` count as 1.

or each `$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);` count as 1?

Comment: The latter is the case.

Comment: Are you closing your connection ?

Comment: @SaadSuri : OMG... I just realised that I never put `$conn->close();` in all my codes. is that what cause the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon RDS Db connections count is persistent connection made by connecting library.
so

`$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);`
will be counted as 1 single connections.

Reason behind increased connections may be bug in your script or library file.
After every successfully select/insert/update/delete actions or performing entire function (at end of cron in your case) **you have to close the mysqli connection**. RDS will not automatically close your connection and hence when your cron runs next time a new connection will be established and counts goes on increasing.